Hold a hitch ball nut in a tight space
I have a 1-7/8 hitch ball installed in the bumper of my 2010 Silverado 1500 for light towing.
The hitch nut is located inside a tight area within the bumper.

How can I hold/secure the nut so that the nut doesn't spin when tightening the hitch? (preferably, using a tool that doesn't need to be held in place by hand, freeing up both hands for wrenching the ball with an adjustable wrench)

What I tried:
If I was using a proper drop hitch that wouldn't block the nut, I'd use 18-inch adjustable wrenches for both the ball and nut. But in this case, the adjustable wrench doesn't fit between the nut and the steel sides of the bumper.
I purchased a 1-1/8 and 1-1/2 in Trailer Hitch Ball Box Wrench. The 1-1/2" end would otherwise fit the nut, there is room on the sides of the nut, but not enough room at the back of the nut.
As a last resort, I jammed a chisel between the nut and the side wall. I need both hands for the adjustable wrench (otherwise, the wrench wants to slip off the ball), so I strapped the chisel in place using a ratchet strap.

That worked, but it made it awkward to use the wrench because the strap was in the way. Unfortunately, I don't have anyone to help hold the chisel.
In the future, is there a better way to hold a nut in place in a tight spot, without needing an extra hand or person?

I'd probably just grind down the sides of a regular open-ended until they fit around the nut and lock themselves against the straight sides. Maybe weld two of them above each other so it can't slip off too far down.

I'd be tempted to throw out the split washer (I think?) and then spot-weld the nut in place.

I was able to use some needle nose vice grips on one of the steel sides. I jammed one of the jaws between the nut an the steel side so that the nut doesn't spin.
